# Virtual function + STL container with base class pointers

Tags: c++, inheritance, stl, overriding, virtual

I have a base class called *Base* which defines a virtual function. The class *Derived* now inherits from it and implements/overwrites that virtual function. The following code works just fine:

```
Base* pB = new Derived();
pB->virtual_function(); // function of class Derived gets called -> good
```

My problem is, that I now store all my derived instances in a STL container `std::map<ID, Base*>`. This seems to cause problems, because when I later iterate over that container and try for each *Base** to call my virtual function, the runtime only recognizes the pointers as type *Base** and does not call the overridden implementation in the class *Derived*.

Is there a way to get that working as intended or am I missing a crucial point here?

**EDIT 1:** Some additional code was requested, so here we go:

```
std::map<ComponentType, Base*> m_Components;
// The factory instantiates a Derived* (via functors) and returns it as Base*
Base* pB = m_pComponentFactory->createComponent(this, type);
// Lazy insert (since there is no map entry with key 'type' at that stage) 
m_Components[type] = pB;

[...]

Base* pB;
for(ComponentMap::const_iterator it = m_Components.begin(); it != m_Components.end( ); ++it) 
{
    pB = it->second;
    pB->virtual_function(); // goes to Base instead of Derived
}
```

**EDIT 2:** One thing I just realized is that I do not call  `dynamic_cast` (or something similar) after creating the Derived instance via the functor (but I wouldn't know what to cast it to anyway since it is all generic/dynamic). It is just a `return creator()` with creator being the functor. Is that the issue?

Definition of creator type (the functon type):

```
typedef Base*(*ComponentCreator)([some params]);
```

**Edit 3:** 
The actual functor is for example defined like this (Renderable and Location being derived classes from Base):

```
&Renderable::Create<Renderable> // or
&Location::Create<Location>
```

with the Create() method being a template function in the class Base.

```
template<typename T> 
static Component* Create([some params]) 
{ 
    return new T([some params]); 
}
```

**EDIT 4:**
The problems seems to be my clone() + CopyConstructor handling. My clone currently looks like this:

```
Base* Base::clone() const
{
    return new Base(*this);
}
```

Since I only create a *Base**, the virtual resolution later on cannot work. The problem I am now left with though, is that I a missing an idea how to change the cloning. As shown in **EDIT 1** I have my `m_Components` map with Base* pointers. I now need to clone them but I only know that they are of *Base** and not of which exact derivative. One idea that comes to mind, might be to store functor used to create the *Derived* instance in the first place in the class, to reuse it later. So my clone would look something like this:

```
Base* Component::clone() const
{
    return m_pCreationFunctor([some params]);
}
```

Anyone seeing a better approach?

Comment: Can you show how you store your elements in the container? In theory, you should not have this problem.

Comment: You did something wrong. The idea is correct and that should work. Are you slicing anywhere by accident?

Comment: When you store them in your container you must somehow be storing a pointer to the base class and not the derived class

Comment: Show the code, how you create the `Derived` objects and how they are stored in your map.

Comment: I added some code excerpts of what seems relevant to me.

Comment: This looks simple enough. I guess there's something wrong with the creation of `Derived` or with the definition of the virtual member function.

Comment: what does createComponent method do ? Can you show us its implementation ?

Comment: I added another edit above already :) .

Comment: No, there's no need to cast a `Derived` to get it as a `Base`.

Comment: Still looks OK so far. The functor is the most obvious place where you might be slicing. Can you post the definition of the specific functor being used here?

Comment: Since everything looks ok so far, try this:  disable copy construction and assignment in the base class to help rule out slicing.  If your compiler supports it, add override to derived class's virtual_function declaration to rule out hiding.

Comment: Never mind, didn't see your your edit 3

Comment: @karunski override did not change anything, but your second hint points in the right direction. Internally I often call clone() + CopyConstructor. Will add an **EDIT 4** with more details.

Comment: That sounds like the problem. If you copy construct a Base, rather than cloning a Base *, you will get slicing

Comment: Usually you just make `clone()` virtual, and implement `Base* Derived::clone() const { return new Derived(*this); }` for each class.

Comment: Looks like the best/only way, although that is unlucky since that means lots of duplicated/redundant code, as now each derived class needs a clone() and a CopyConstructor which all basically look the same, since the layout of most derived classes looks the same. But I guess I have to live with that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are a victim of slicing. When you copy construct a Base, you will lose the Derived parts of the object. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing for a bit more detail. If the base class is not supposed to be instantiated, you might consider making it abstract to prevent making this mistake in future.

The fix in this case is probably to have a virtual Base * clone() method and override it in derived classes.

i.e.

```
class Base{
...
virtual Base * clone() const = 0;
...
};

class Derived : public Base {
...
Base * clone() const override { return new Derived(*this); }
...
};
```

If you really want to avoid rewriting the clone method, you could use an intermediate [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) class i.e

```
struct Base{
    virtual Base * clone() = 0;
};

template <typename D>
struct B : public Base {
    virtual Base * clone() { return new D(*static_cast<D*>(this)); }
};

struct D : public B<D>{};
```

Comment: Might as well take advantage of covariant return type as well :)

Comment: Yeh - thought it was best to keep it simple though!